# Is it possible to generate this query?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

`Select * From table1`.
if `table1.field1=1` then inner join `table2`
else if `table1.field1=2` then inner join `table3`

Comment: It makes no sense. Instead - explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Your logic hints at what you want, but what are the join conditions between the tables?

Comment: To answer your question. No. Your query does not make sense. You can use Case Statement for replacement for if-else condition, or @zohar's answer seems to answer what you want to achieve on your query.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this, even though it's not entirely clear from your question:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON <join condition> AND t1.field1 = 1
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON <join condition> AND t1.field1 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT glbank.check_num
, glbank.ref_num
, glbank.check_amt
, glbank.check_date
, glbank.bank_code
, vendaddr.name
, vendor.vend_num 
, vendor.vend_remit
FROM ((aptrxp_all
INNER JOIN glbank 
ON aptrxp_all.check_num=glbank.check_num) 
INNER JOIN vendaddr 
ON aptrxp_all.vend_num=vendaddr.vend_num) 
INNER JOIN vendor
ON vendaddr.vend_num=vendor.vend_num
If vendaddr.vend_num=vendor.vend_num Then
(SELECT vendaddr.name
FROM vendaddr 
INNER JOIN vendor
ON vendaddr.vend_num=vendor.vend_num where vendaddr.vend_num=vendor.vend_num)
Else (SELECT vendaddr.name
FROM vendaddr 
INNER JOIN vendor
ON vendaddr.vend_num=vendor.vend_remit where 
vendaddr.vend_num=vendor.vend_remit)
end 
where glbank.check_amt= @amount
```